# Creating a new data frame column, by splitting a string in another column in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm trying to break down some data I have in a data frame, that looks like this for example:

```
Index   Name
0       joe bloggs
1       jane doe
2       first last
```

I want to create a new column, with just the last name for example.

I feel like I should be doing something along the lines of `df['New_name'] = df['Name'].split()` but I know that won't work.

Any help would be really appreciated, cheers

Comment: `df.Name.str.split(' ', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'First', 1: 'Last'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also do the trick:

```
df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[-1]

0    bloggs
1       doe
2      last
```

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot mate, one more quick question, how can I then edit them in the sense that some last names are van der vaart for example. I know 'string.replace(' ', '-')' works ordinarily but it wont go thru the whole column and edit any one that fits the bill. I then want to convert all to lower case?

Comment: lower case - you would just chain `.str.lower()`  onto the above answer. As for double or triple worded surnames... very difficult if they are only separated with a space. I imagine you'd need some custom regex to parse those.

Comment: that's great thats worked, i found this 's.replace(' ', '_') for s in listings' to help with replacing the white spaces fyi. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

`df['New_name'] = df['Name'].str.split(expand =True)[1]` gets the second word. If you want to make sure you get the last word, `df['New_name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])` works.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Comment: @Accumulation Do you mean `df['Name'].str.split(expand =True)[1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

String handling in pandas series is a little weird. How about

`df1['firstname'],df1['lastname']=df1['name'].str.split().str`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help